# Delete a file in Linux irrespective of it being open

Tags: linux

I am trying to delete files while archiving, using:

```
  rm -Rf /test/this/path/.
```

but when I run this command I am getting this error:

> Device or resource busy

This is due to the file being open by some other user.

Now, how can I delete a file irrespective of whether it is open?